# Elasticsearch not starting on Cuckoo

Tags: elasticsearch, cuckoo

Running elasticsearch on Cuckoo Sandbox.

After the installation elastic search not able to start.

curl -X GET 'http://localhost:9200' returns with connection refused.

Firewall is already off.

This are the errors appearing from Elastic search status:

```
Sht 09 17:19:24 cuckoo systemd[1]: Starting Elasticsearch...
Sht 09 17:20:39 cuckoo systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: start operation timed out. Terminating.
Sht 09 17:20:40 cuckoo systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
Sht 09 17:20:40 cuckoo systemd[1]: Failed to start Elasticsearch.
Sht 13 15:06:01 cuckoo systemd[1]: Starting Elasticsearch...
Sht 13 15:07:05 cuckoo systemd-entrypoint[24123]: uncaught exception in thread [main]
Sht 13 15:07:05 cuckoo systemd-entrypoint[24123]: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to obtain node locks, tried [[/var/lib/elasticsear>
Sht 13 15:07:05 cuckoo systemd-entrypoint[24123]: Likely root cause: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /var/lib/elasticsearch/nodes/0/nod>
Sht 13 15:07:05 cuckoo systemd-entrypoint[24123]:         at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:90)
Sht 13 15:07:05 cuckoo systemd-entrypoint[24123]:         at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:106)
Sht 13 15:07:05 cuckoo systemd-entrypoint[24123]:         at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:111)
Sht 13 15:07:05 cuckoo systemd-entrypoint[24123]:         at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newFileChannel(UnixFileSystemProvid>
```

The network.host on Elasticsearch config file has already been changed.

Comment: Please refrain from taking screenshots of text. Instead, copy-paste the text directly in the question. This will improve the odds of getting an answer. Also, please provide more details. What is your current configuration? Have you done some debugging? Have you looked into the journal? Have you tried something to solve this issue on your own?

Comment: another +1 to not taking screenshots of text. you really need to look at your Elasticsearch logs to find out what the issue is